# Shibboleth Session Unauthorized

Tags: apache, shibboleth

My experience with Shibboleth is limited and I have no access to configuration or logs on the IdP or the SP. I am trying to troubleshoot this issue:

Previous Shibboleth session is still active on the client workstation. When attempting to access document protected by the following .htaccess configuration:

```
AuthType shibboleth
ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
require valid-user
```

The client (occasionally) receives the following error message:

```
Authorization Failed

Based on the information provided to this application about you, you are not authorized to access the resource at "http://myresourcepath"

Please contact the administrator of this service or application if you believe this to be an error
```

In troubleshooting, I changed .htaccess from

```
require valid-user
```

to:

```
require shib-session
```

I thought the issue might be the deprecated parameter- but after changing, I was still receiving the authorization failed message. The only way to successfully authorize is to clear the browser cache, revisit the page which then it prompts for authentication, and then authorization passes its check and you hit the page successfully with no error.

What complicates matters even more, is, when .htaccess is set to:

```
require shib-session
```

The authorization error message persists even after clearing the cache and re-authenticating. I had to change .htaccess back to

```
require valid-user
```

I dont know what could cause the random authorization issue, if the session wasn't valid, the user would get directed to the idp for login, correct? Thats Shibboleth's design. So, the session has to be valid- but why does it not recognize the user as authorized for that resource?

Additionally:

after I received the message and googled quickly, it seems like a stock response from the idp:

https://technical.bestgrid.org/index.php/Vladimir's_general_Shiboleth_notes

says:

This specific example asks for the user variable to be set to any value - and any Shibboleth attribute can be used with the variable name it is assigned to in the Attribute Acceptance policy (AAP.xml). For more syntax on using the require directive, see the examples in the SP htaccess documentation on specific features implemented for the Apache require directive.
Users who do not have the attribute (or do not provide it), get the following error message (with the Shibboleth logo). .... is same message....

This form of control however may not be that user friendly - user would have to know to go either use Autograph to allow the release of the attribute, or talk to their IdP administrator to configure the attributes on the IdP.
Also note that this does not work with lazy sessions - in which case one immediately gets the same error message.
Further, note that care must be taken with overlapping  access control blocks. These should be listed from the most-generic ("/") to the most specific (as "/secure" in the above example). Otherwise, the more relaxed settings on the generic one would override the more stringent settings on the specific one.

Comment: Error message you're receiving on the client - where is that coming from? Maybe there is some logic outside of the Shibboleth setup triggering this

Comment: more added under 'additionally'